# Android market publish (application language settings): "Fill fields with auto translation from English"

Tags: android, google-play

Under Android publish > your application > language > add language is option **Fill fields with auto translation from English (en)**

[image]

What does it do? Does it translate my application to all possible languages automatically depending on user selected locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just take the English text (if any) and fill the languages you selected with the translation.

It only apply for the market descriptions.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. **Note**: you have to tick this box while you are adding the language. If you have already added the language, then you can not auto-translate the app description/info.